# Excessive Logging from DefaultPromise

Tags: netty

When using a PromiseAggregator, I am finding that it is producing an excessive amount of WARN-level logging:

```
@Test
public void warning() {

    EventExecutor executor = ImmediateEventExecutor.INSTANCE;  

    // Create a promise, to be completed by the aggregate
    DefaultChannelPromise promiseForAggregate = new DefaultChannelPromise(null, executor);
    PromiseAggregator<Void, DefaultChannelPromise> aggregate = new PromiseAggregator<>(promiseForAggregate, false);

    // Add the underlying promises to the aggregate 
    DefaultChannelPromise underlyingPromise1 = new DefaultChannelPromise(null, executor);
    DefaultChannelPromise underlyingPromise2 = new DefaultChannelPromise(null, executor); 
    DefaultChannelPromise underlyingPromise3 = new DefaultChannelPromise(null, executor); 
    aggregate.add(underlyingPromise1, underlyingPromise2, underlyingPromise3);

    // (A) First promise fails, OK!
    underlyingPromise1.setFailure(new NullPointerException());

    // (B) WARN!
    underlyingPromise2.setFailure(new NullPointerException());
    // (C) WARN!
    underlyingPromise3.setFailure(new NullPointerException());
}
```

When the code reaches point `(A)` the first underlying promise (`promise1`) is completed with a failure. This, in turn, will faile the `promiseForAggregate` through the notification mechanisms used by the `PromiseAggregate`.

At point `(B)`, the second failure will cause `promiseForAggregate` to be marked as failed for a second time, thus triggering the following WARN:

```
2015-10-12 15:37:37 WARN  DefaultPromise:151 - An exception was thrown by io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseAggregator.operationComplete()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: complete already: DefaultChannelPromise@2a5ca609(failure(java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseAggregator.operationComplete(PromiseAggregator.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:567)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:87)
    at TestAggregateFuture.warning(TestAggregateFuture.java:31)
    ....
```

This is completely useless logging! By the very nature of a `PromiseAggregator`, we can expect there to be scenarios when there are multiple underlying failures.

---

Within my application, I am writing a large (chunked) HTTP object to a client. I am using a `PromiseAggregator` to aggregate the promises from each chunked write. As a result, if the client disconnects part-way through a large write, I can end up with the above exception printed thousands of times in the log file.

---

The only (remotely) sensible solution I have come-up with is to override the implementation of `promiseForAggregate`:

```
DefaultChannelPromise promiseForAggregate = new DefaultChannelPromise(null, executor) {
    @Override
    public ChannelPromise setFailure(Throwable cause) {
        if (! super.isDone()) {
            super.setFailure(cause);
        }
        return this;
    }
};
```

I am left wondering if I have overlooked some simpler option? This seems like a rather vanilla use-case, so I feel uneasy in hacking a solution together of this nature.